# Map 624 could not be created for player GUID + unable to zone in while an encounter is in progress (Wintergrasp)

Tags: azerothcore

In the `worldserver.conf` I have disabled all Wintergrasp processing with the following option

```
Wintergrasp.Enable = 2
```

When I look at the Wintergrasp map no encounter is in progress, the doors to VOA are open but when I try to enter the VOA raid I get teleported back to my hearthstone location and receive the message:

> unable to zone in while an encounter is in progress

The worldserver output shows:

> Map 624 could not be created for player GUID Full: 0x0000000000000001 Type: Player Low: 1, porting player to homebind

I have tried changing the worldserver config `Wintergrasp.Enable` from `0` to `1` or `2` and it didn't have any effect on the in-game error `unable to zone in while an encounter is in progress` or the worldserver output error `Map 624 could not be created for player GUID Full: 0x0000000000000001 Type: Player Low: 1, porting player to homebind`

I also tried to see if it timed out but after 4 hours of letting the server run, the error remained the same when trying to enter the VOA raid.

Any tips on how to clear/fully disable the Wintergrasp encounter so I can enter VOA without being teleporter back to my hearthstone location when entering the raid?

Comment: Tested this with a clean build of azerothcore without any modules or custom sql + scripts and got the latest build from azerothcore and still have the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by setting the AzerothCore Wintergrasp enable setting to `0` so the battleground is disabled but processing is enabled and set the timers for the battle duration to `1` and nobattle timer to 90 minutes. This causes it to finish processing and after processing, it opens up for horde/alliance every 80 minutes with a 1-minute battle in between where you can't zone in. There is a check though in the source that whenever the counter is below 10 minutes you will be unable to zone in. So thats why the nobattle timer should be on 90 minute+. Both factions can enter the raid portal for VOA if you have an option to teleport over there for players

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution @Dkap please check the edits I did to your original question for better formatting